# Organize MongoDB request on Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, performance, mongoose

I'm actually creating a chat like Discord with servers and channels using Node.JS, MongoDB and Mongoose.
Actually, my structure is this one:

https://github.com/copostic/My-Simple-Chat/tree/master/models
But to get the conversations, I have to make so much nested functions and I would like to know if there was a better way to organize my code..
Here's the code with the nested functions, I'm trying to get the message list of each channel of each server:

```
"use strict"

const Server = require('../models/server'),
    Channel = require('../models/channel'),
    Message = require('../models/message'),
    User = require('../models/user');

exports.getChannels = function (req, res, next) {
    // Only return one message from each conversation to display as snippet
    Server.find({members: req.session._id})
        .select('_id')
        .exec(function (err, servers) {

            if (err) {
                res.send({ error: err });
                return next(err);
            }

            servers.forEach(function (server) {
                Channel.find({ serverId: server })
                .exec(function (err, channels) {
                    // Set up empty array to hold conversations + most recent message
                    let fullConversations = [];
                    channels.forEach(function (channel) {
                        Message.find({
                                'channelId': channel._id
                            })
                            .sort('creationDate')
                            .limit(1)
                            .populate({
                                path: "author",
                                select: "profile.firstName profile.lastName"
                            });
                        .exec(function (err, message) {
                            if (err) {
                                res.send({
                                    error: err
                                });
                                return next(err);
                            }
                            fullConversations.push(message);
                            if (fullConversations.length === conversations.length) {
                                return res.status(200).json({
                                    conversations: fullConversations
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
};
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you please edit the question posting an example of the expected output?

Comment: You should look up libraries like [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) or [bluebird](https://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) to organize your code.